# asyncantask with asyntask with background process

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The following code gives a Force Close Error

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            new loadSomeStuff().execute();

        }
    });
}
  public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    ProgressDialog dlg;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dlg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        dlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dlg.setMessage("Loding Please Wait");
        dlg.setMax(100);
        dlg.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            try {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                                +  "/bg.pdf"));
                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph("hie"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Generated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                document.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(5);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(88);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        dlg.dismiss();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdated(Integer... progress) {

        dlg.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.setText("DONE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you attach error log? In line PftWriter.getInstance(document, ... change remove one "/" - PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/bg.pdf"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to dismiss a dialog from a non ui thread, the `doInBackground` method may **not** call interface stuff. Remove the `dlg.dismiss();` from there and put it on the `onPostExecute` method, which **can modify ui**.

To clarify, `doInBackground` as the name suggests, is a *background* thread that has no direct control over the user interface, that's why when you try to dismiss the dialog, it will fail.

Need coffee.

Answer (score 1):

In AsynTask,only doInBackGround() works at **background thread**

That means u can access the UI Element in other Methods Like **onPostExceute(),onPreExceute(),onProgressUpdated()**
not in doInBackground()

Removed dlg.dismiss() and it's Done

[code and concept here](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/01/asynctask-android-example.html)